# Property setters for compound assignment?

Tags: python

Consider the following simple example class, which has a property that exposes a modified version of some internal data when called:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value, offset=0):
        self._value = value
        self.offset = offset

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value + self.offset

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value
```

The `value.setter` works fine for regular assignment, but of course breaks down for compound assignment:

```
>>> x = Foo(3, 2)
>>> x.value
5
>>> x.value = 2
>>> x.value
4
>>> x.value += 5
>>> x.value
11
```

The desired behavior is that `x.value += 5` should be equivalent to `x.value = x._value + 5`, as opposed to `x.value = x.value + 5`. Is there any way to achieve this (with the property interface) purely within the `Foo` class?

Comment: I recommend against adding magical numeric behavior from the beginning to a property, otherwise you break symmetry – as you've noticed – with the standard mathematical operators. Defining `offsetValue()` makes the intention far more obvious to the reader; in particular, should `x.value += 5` add to `_value` or `offset`?

Comment: I tried something with `if 'INPLACE_ADD' in [dis.opname[ord(op)] for op in inspect.stack()[1][0].f_code.co_code]:` before realizing that the `setter` behavior overall is flawed. I'd been working with it so long it didn't occur to me to just revisit that.

Comment: It seems to work ok without that offset.  I agree with ezod that it is doing something odd attempting to assign the results of the add to the computed property.  With the offset it gives unexpected results.  Without it it doesn't.  Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ezod, there is no direct way to do what you're asking for, even with the descriptors protocol. 
That kind behaviour of `value` property totally breaks the semantics of `+=` operator.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How does it break `+=` semantics? Externally, it would work exactly as expected. The "offset" functionality (which is trivial in this example but rather involved in my actual application) is hidden from the user, but the user should still be able to intuitively access and modify the exposed value using all the functionality of its class (including `__iadd__`) without these weird effects.

Comment: On further reflection I think I see what you mean -- `x += y` should equate to `x = x + y`, which is not true in my case. Fair enough.

Comment: Consider this: y = x.value; x.value += 5; y += 5; At this point, a programmer expects that x == y.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `__iadd__` magic method.

<sub>You need to do that because `+=` *means* "take the value and add five, then set that as the result". If you want it to know that the value isn't really the value, you need to change the semantics of the `+=` operator.</sub>

Comment: Overriding `__iadd__` in `Foo` will not work, as I am not adding to `Foo`, I am adding to its member. Even if I have access to the class of `value` and there is no polymorphism, it has no knowledge of `Foo` internals, so I can't override `__iadd__` there either.

Comment: `__iadd__` is also only called on mutable types, otherwise `__add__` is called. Also, try writing semantics by which this works, by sublcassing the value passed -- you'll end up recursing no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted with the same problem and solved it with the following method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._y = 0

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y + 5

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        value -= 5
        self._y = value


>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.y
5
>>> f.y += 1
>>> f._y
1
>>> f.y
6
```

Could this be a solution? Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

> The desired behavior is that x.value += 5 should be equivalent to
>   x.value = x._value + 5

Why should Python know how you property is implemented (i.e. that `setter` assigns its value exactly to `_x`)?

Protocol of `property` gives you a possibility assign different actions (get, set, delete) to one name.  And this protocol doesn't care about a way of implementation of these actions.

So it would be quite confusable if Python make some assumptions about your code and try to modify strait forward code logic.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that Python should know this. More along the lines of `setter` being able to introspect how it was called (i.e. via `=`, `+=`, etc.) and behave accordingly.